# Create an empty table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create an empty table. I would add the data to this table via a separate job.
So , I don't have any predefined dataset .
I used this query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
test_ds.table1
(
  col1 string
)
```

But this gave an error

```
Not found: Dataset <default_project_name>:test_ds was not found in location US
```

In scenarios , where we want to create an empty table and define the schema and then add the data to it separately , how do we proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [create a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset) first:

```
CREATE SCHEMA test_ds
```